# Is the "I have no work" post too specific to use as a reference post for "duplicates"?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[What can I do at work when I have no work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/what-can-i-do-at-work-when-i-have-no-work)

This post is roughly "I've unsuccessfully tried everything to get more work, what do I do with my time?"

As such, the answers, especially the top-voted one, don't really focus on what one should actually try to get more "official" work and instead mostly advise to just give up and do other self-improvement things.

Then questions like the following are closed as duplicates, despite the advice being wildly inappropriate for that situation: (since finding more "official" work is very much core to the advice given there)

- [Should I ask for work from my team leader when the project is almost complete?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/should-i-ask-for-work-from-my-team-leader-when-the-project-is-almost-complete)
- [Should i ask for more work , when i have completed all the tasks assigned to me for the day?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59667/should-i-ask-for-more-work-when-i-have-completed-all-the-tasks-assigned-to-me)
- [What can I do if work pace is too slow for me](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56777/what-can-i-do-if-work-pace-is-too-slow-for-me)

What should be done here?

Do we have a more general post on this which can be used as a reference post instead?

Comment: I agree, the usual advice doesn't apply, as it is "go find more work" or "talk to your boss", et cetera.  This one is more "what do I do when I've exhausted all of these options.